# Restrict tag value modification

Tags: azure

I am writing to ask your assistance regarding an important Azure topic.

- Scenario 1:

I have 30 different resources in Azure in different resource groups in a subscription. There is a tag (owner) on all resources. If the value of owner tag is a username the only person who will be able to modify the owner tag is the user whose username is equal the owner tag's value. Of course if user1 modified the owner tag's value to another existing username (user2) user1 wouldn't be able to modify the owner tag's value. In this case the only person who could modify the owner tag's value is user2. **Is it possible to restrict tag value modification at any Azure resources?**

- Scenario 2:

I have 30 different resources in Azure in different resource groups in a subscription. I create a custom role (ops-role) which has similar privileges in Azure than a Contributor except this role doesn't have privilege to modify the tags and tags' value. Then I create a another custom role (tagger-role) which has only (or almost only) tag modification privileges. **Is it possible to create these roles in Azure?**

I need a solution for the 1st or the 2nd scenario. I would like to restrict the tags modification on the Azure resources.

Answer (score 0):

1. no, this is not possible, you have to create your own api on top of azure
2. if my memory servers me well, there is no separate role for tags, anyone with write permission over the resource can tag so this is essentially not achievable, you need a custom api on top of azure to do that